# Is it ok to use product's description in meta description?

Tags: php, html, tags, product, meta

For example say a user is selling a computer. The title of the product and the description of the product will go in the meta tags like this.

```
<title><?php echo $product_title; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $product_desc; ?>" />
```

Is that correct way of doing things on a user based website?  If so, what if the product description is like 500 characters? Is that too long for meta tags? Should it be cut?

Comment: Technically speaking it can be whatever you like, and any length. Whether it conforms to SEO rules/standards/practise is an entirely different (and off topic) matter

Comment: You might want to include it somewhere in the page itself (not in a metatag), however, it won't cause any problem. Search engines generally truncate snippets longer than 160 characters (results vary).

Comment: I do have it on the page itself but i guess it's good to keep it in meta tags and less than 160 char, for SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that approach is fine but you should also use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). For example:

```
<title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product_title); ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($product_desc); ?>" />
```

Regarding the length of the meta description. [Google has the answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=meta+description+length&oq=meta+description+length&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4432j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=106&ie=UTF-8):

> Meta descriptions can be any length, but search engines generally truncate snippets longer than 160 characters. It is best to keep meta descriptions between 150 and 160 characters.

So, if you would like to do the work for the search engines you can truncate the meta description by using [substr](http://php.net/substr).

```
<?php
    echo '<title>'.htmlspecialchars($product_title).'</title>'.
         '<meta name="description" content="'.htmlspecialchars(substr($product_desc,0,160)).'" />';
?>
```

Comment: I'd say do the work- for one simple line of code, the page size will decrease a fair chunk. No point having redundant stuff that only the scraper thiefs see!